# Connection refused for 127.0.0.1:5433 postgresql node js

Tags: node.js, postgresql, database-connection, ports, connection-refused

I have node js server that works perfectly on my local machine. While setting up on the server, it throws an error : Connection Refused.

Here are the details:

```
pg_config = "postgres://postgres@localhost:5433/crda_test"; 
or pg_config = "postgres://postgres@::1:5433/crda_test"; 
or pg_config = "postgres://postgres@127.0.0.1:5433/crda_test";
```

About postgresql :

```
Version: 9.6 postgresql 
psql -U postgres  -h localhost  -p 5433 (This works perfectly fine)
psql -U postgres  -h ::1  -p 5433 (This works perfectly fine)
psql -U postgres  -h 127.0.0.1  -p 5433 (This works perfectly fine)
```

Output for this command given below:

> sudo lsof -n -u postgres |grep LISTEN (Output of this given below)

```
postgres 15072 postgres    3u  IPv6           15677592      0t0      TCP [::1]:5433 (LISTEN)
postgres 29773 postgres    3u  IPv6           15519790      0t0      TCP [::1]:5435 (LISTEN)
```

This command shows that port is listening and why am I not able to make a request. It helps me a lot if someone can throw some light on this. 
Below is the error while running the server on remote machine:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ud2Oh.png)

Comment: `127.0.0.1` is an IPv4 address and it looks like your Postgres is only bound to IPv6. Try using `::1` or `localhost` for your connection address. You could also try getting it to bind to IPv4.

Comment: Hey even that gives the same error. I have tried with ::1 and localhost both. BTW i have removed md5 and added trust in pg_hba.conf. Doest it effect this? or Any firewall blocking?

Comment: Do you allow localhost connections in pg_hba.conf?  (If not, you should see the rejected connections in pg_log)

Comment: Do you have iptables running on the server?  Could it have been configured to block localhost connections?